# Return to code after function runs

Tags: python, text-based

I'm making a text-based game and need an application-wide command line that's able to be pulled up at any text entry. My plan was to have the commands contained within a module, and execute command(), which would then allow the user to enter a command (or get a list) that is then run (contained within the same module). This didn't work because I need a way to return to where the user was. Is there anyway to return to where the user was before they entered command mode, or is there a better way to do this?

This was my idea:

```
import commands

def something():
    print "a question"

    action = raw_input("> ")

    if action == "command":
        commands.commands()
    elif "something else" in action:
        do something
    else:
        error.error(1)
        something()
```

Which then went to commands.py:

```
def commands():
    print "Enter a command, help for a list, blah blah blah."

    command = raw_input("$ ")

    if command == "bag":
        bag()
    elif command == "other":
        other()

def bag():
    print "Action listing things in bag"
```

The problem is returning where the user left off.

Comment: lol look at the adventure module ... and look at its source ... maybe

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what your saying. Care to clarify?

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a main game loop:

```
while game.is_running:
    command = get_user_input()
    user_do(command)
    update_world()
```

This will repeat the three lines of code inside the `while` loop for as long as `game.is_running` is `True`. First, you get the user input. Next, you act on it. Finally, you perform any other updates your game needs, like moving or spawning monsters. At this point, it loops back and asks the user for another command.

**Update:** here is a working example:

```
# In commands.py:
def bag():
    print 'bag'

def other():
    print 'other'

def unrecognized():
    print 'unknown command'

# In main.py:
import commands

def user_input():
    print 'a question'
    return raw_input('>')

def user_do(command):
    # get the matching command out of commands, or pass back
    # the unrecognized function if it's not found
    action = getattr(commands, command, commands.unrecognized)
    action()

is_running = True
while is_running:
    command = user_input()
    if command == 'quit':
        is_running = False
    else:
        user_do(command)
```

In this example, I've cheated and am relying on the user input commands being identical to the name of the functions to be called. In `user_do`, the `getattr` call compares the string the user has input with the contents of the `command` module, returning the function of the same name if one exists, or the fallback function `unrecognized` if it doesn't. `action` will now either hold the command function or `unrecognized`.

If you don't want to have your user commands so tightly bound to the actual functions themselves, you can use a `dict` as a branching construct (or *dispatch*) instead of having a lot of `if / elif / else` statements:

```
# Modified main.py
import commands

COMMAND_DISPATCH = {
    'bag': commands.bag,
    'sack': commands.bag,
    'other': commands.other,
    # ...
}

# ...

def user_do(command):
    action = COMMAND_DISPATCH.get(command, commands.unrecognized)
    action()
```

In this example, rather than look up the functions in the `commands` module, we look them up in `COMMAND_DISPATCH` instead.

One more bit of advice: pretty soon you'll want to look at parsing the user input into more than just a single command. For this example, let's assume you want to be able to accept input of the form "command   ... ". You can extend the `user_input` function to take care of this:

```
def user_input():
    print 'a question'
    user_input = raw_input('>').split(' ')
    command = user_input[0]
    arguments = user_input[1:]
    return command, arguments
```

So if you enter 'foo bar baz', this would return the tuple `('foo', ['bar', 'baz'])`. Next we update the main loop to deal with the arguments.

```
while is_running:
    # use tuple unpacking to split into command, argument pairs
    command, arguments = user_input()
    if command == 'quit':
        is_running = False
    else:
        user_do(command, arguments)
```

Then make sure we pass them to the command:

```
def user_do(command, arguments):
    action = COMMAND_DISPATCH.get(command, commands.unrecognized)
    action(arguments)
```

And finally, we modify the commands to accept and handle the arguments:

```
def bag(arguments):
    for argument in arguments:
        print 'bagged ', argument
```

For a text adventure, you'll want a more substantial parser, something that deals with `command object`, `command object preposition subject`, and possibly even `command adjective object ...`.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. I need the option to run a command when the user is allowed input (answering the questions), and I'm not sure how I would implement you're suggestion.

Comment: I've added a working example of what I mean. But really, if looping constructs are confusing to you here, I highly recommend starting with some Python tutorials.

Comment: It's not the looping constructs confusing me, it was how the user interacted with the game. My idea involved printing a question, prompting user for input, then looking for keywords and executing a different module. If you wouldn't mind briefly describing how prompting and user input worked in your example, I would greatly appreciate it.  This is actually for a Python tutorial, so I'm kind of new to it.

Comment: Sorry, that's probably way more than you wanted, but hopefully it'll be of help :)

Comment: I understood most of that! It's a little further advanced than I am at the moment, but I really appreciate the attempt! I'll just downgrade the project to something the tutorial is more likely expecting, and after some more learning implement your method in the current game idea. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You should research "python finite state machine". It is pretty much exactly what you want.

- [Charming Python: Using state machines](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-python-state/index.html)
- [Finite-state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_state_machine)
- [wiki.python.org/moin/FiniteStateMachine](http://wiki.python.org/moin/FiniteStateMachine)

> What is a state machine?
>
> An overly accurate description of a state machine is that it is a
>   directed graph, consisting of a set of nodes and a corresponding set
>   of transition functions. The machine "runs" by responding to a series
>   of events. Each event is in the domain of the transition function
>   belonging to the "current" node, where the function's range is a
>   subset of the nodes. The function returns the "next" (perhaps the
>   same) node. At least one of these nodes must be an end-state. When an
>   end-state is reached, the machine stops.
>
> When to use a state machine ...
>
> 1. Start in an initial state.
> 2. Read a line of input.
> 3. Depending on the input and the current state, either transition to a new state or process the line as appropriate for the current state.

Similar to what @MatthewTrevor suggested in his answer, you would have a main loop, and pass a "state" context to the first entry point call (`start` or `intro` or whatever). That call can change the state context to point at something else. When control reaches back to the main loop again and it checks the state, it will run the new state.